# Maintaining model structure during indexing with django-haystack and elasticsearch

Tags: django-haystack

I am trying to index shop information which is stored in django's Shop model with a one to one mapping to Address model.

During indexing I don't want to flatten the data, I want to maintain the object graph and store address as a nested object of shop in elasticsearch. Is it even possible with haystack?

Comment: What exactly is your concern? You can flatten the Shop->Address relationship when indexing and later when you get results back from haystack you can access the `Address` object via `result.object.address`

Comment: Elasticsearch allows to store JSON object structure without flattening it and that what I would like to do.